# Compiling AWS Beanstalk built using powershell instead of Visual Studio

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

When I use Visual Studio to publish to AWS Beanstalk, Visual Studio compiles an application deployment package to push it to AWS Beanstalk.

Can I replicate that process using AWS PowerShell or PowerShell in general?